# Where does the vs-code-runner extension get the information to build and run Kotlin programs?

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I have a simple `main.kt` file in VS Code:

```
fun main() {
  println("Hello world");
}
```

I tried pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> (I have a Node background) and it says "You don't have an extension for debugging Kotlin." I installed `vscode-runner` by HarryHopkinson. <kbd>F5</kbd> still give the same message, but <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-N</kbd> builds and runs the program. It seems to be executing the following:

> cd "d:\Documents\kotlin\hello" && kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar && java -jar main.jar

From where does `vscode-runner` get the parameters to execute this set of instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just uses the executor map setting. The default value is defined in https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/package.json, where it currently has the following:

```json
".kt": "cd $dir && kotlinc $fileName -include-runtime -d $fileNameWithoutExt.jar && java -jar $fileNameWithoutExt.jar",
".kts": "kotlinc -script",
```

More info about the executor map setting and the template variables that can be used in it can be found at https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration.

<kbd>F5</kbd>'s default binding in VS Code is the following:

> ```json
> { "key": "f5", "command": "debug.openView",
>                   "when": "!debuggersAvailable" },
> { "key": "f5", "command": "workbench.action.debug.start",
>                   "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState == 'inactive'" },
> { "key": "f5", "command": "workbench.action.debug.continue",
>                   "when": "debugState == 'stopped'" },
> ```